# sonarqube7.2.1--how to get persistence reports

Tags: sonarqube

How can I get a persistence reports. I want to get a html/pdf file that can save the data（like this picture） after I scan my code each time. Every time I run the sonar-runner, the new report will cover the last version. What should I do to check the old report after I run scanner many times. Or，can I get a local html/pdf file to save the old version. Thanks!
[html/pdf file like this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txRUg.jpg)

Comment: Maybe using [webhooks](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Webhooks) can solve your problem. What part of Sonarqube is producing this report?

Comment: I don't get how to use webhooks to save data, I will check the doc again after. I just update my description maybe it is clearer now.

Comment: From the documentation: "Typically, webhooks would be used to notify external tools of the Quality Gate statuses of your projects. Most typically it is the processing of an analysis report that triggers the webhooks". Look at the example output provided. If that is not enough you can use the WEB API to get more information. You can not get a HTML of PDF output.